# Proving that $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^n \mathrm dx =\frac{1}{n {2n\choose n}}$

Tags: integration, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am working on the following problem and I've arrived at an integral which I need to show equals the proposition.

> Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{k=n}\dfrac{(-1)^{k}{n\choose k}}{n+k}=\dfrac{1}{n{2n\choose n}}$.

---

**My Attempt**:

Let us consider for the sake of convenience the notation ${n\choose k}=\text{C}_k$
$$\begin{aligned}(1-x)^n&=\text{C}_0-\text{C}_1x+\text{C}_2x^2-\text{C}_3x^3+\ldots+(-1)^{n}\text{C}_nx^n\\ \int _{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^n \mathrm dx&=\int_{0}^{1}\text{C}_0x^{n-1}-\text{C}_1x^n+\text{C}_2x^{n+1}+\ldots+(-1)^{n}\text{C}_nx^{2n-1}\mathrm dx\\ \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^n \mathrm dx&=\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\text{C}_k}{n+k}\end{aligned}$$

---

I now need  to prove that the integral equals $\left[{2n\choose n}\right]^{-1}$. But I am unclear on how to proceed with simplifying the integral. I would appreciate any hints apart from usage of Integration by Parts technique. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Look into the beta function and its relation to the gamma function.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Hint: use integration by parts.

Comment: @ante.ceperic Could you demonstrate. I am not familiar with that technique.

Comment: I think Apéry proved a similar identity in the first part of his proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$, i.e., that $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^3} = \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3 \binom{2n}{n}}$

Comment: Ante's suggestion (integration by parts) is probably better than mine (beta function)...

Comment: @peterag I got the equality from the Beta Function. Thanks

Comment: see this nice answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771954/bayes-billiard-balls-probability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's put
$$I_{k,n} = \int_0^1 x^k (1-x)^n dx.$$
By [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) we have:
$$I_{k,n} = \frac{n}{k+1} I_{k+1, n-1}. $$
Now we can iterate this to get
$$ I_{k,n} = \frac{n}{k+1} I_{k+1,n-1} = \frac{n}{k+1} \frac{n-1}{k+2} I_{k+2, n-2} = \ldots = \frac{n!}{(k+1)(k+2) \ldots (k+n)} I_{k+n,0}. (*)$$

We have $$I_{k+n,0} = \int_0^1 x^{k+n} dx = \frac{1}{k+n+1}.$$
Now it remains to write the fraction from $(*)$ as a binomial coefficient.

Comment: Thanks. I thought partial integration as you mentioned first was something different from by parts. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^n dx= \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)} =\frac{(n-1)! n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{1}{n{2n \choose n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{d(x^m(1-x)^n)}{dx}=mx^{m-1}(1-x)^n-nx^m(1-x)^{n-1}$$

Integrate both sides wrt $x,$  $$x^m(1-x)^n=mI(m-1,n)-nI(m,n-1)$$ where $$I(m,n)=\int x^m(1-x)^n\ dx,J(m,n)=\int_0^1x^m(1-x)^n\ dx$$

and $$J(m-1,n)=\dfrac nm\cdot J(m,n-1)$$
$$=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{m(m-1)}\cdot J(m+1,n-2)$$
$$=\cdots$$
$$=\dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{m(m-1)\cdots(m-r+1)}\cdot J(m+r-1,n-r)$$

$r=n\implies$ $$J(m-1,n)=\dfrac{n!
}{m(m-1)\cdots(m-n+1)}\cdot J(m+n-1,0)$$

$\displaystyle J(m+n-1,0)=\dfrac1{m+n}$

Finally set $m=n$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps,

Let $$I = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n}dx = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{n-1}x^{n}dx$$
Therefore $$2I = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx$$
Let, $$x = sin^2(u) $$
$$dx = 2sin(u)cos(u)du$$
$$2I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}2sin^{2n-1}(u)cos^{2n-1}(u)du$$ for which standard results exist